# VBA Macro security in file with Addin Workbooks_Open Event

Tags: vba, add-in

I have question about macro security in file with an add-in. I've created add-in that will be instaled in my department. This add-in have some macros that are responsible for formating, displaying messages etc. There is also Workbooks_Open event to display information about some data stored in the file (as MsgBox at opening a file). I am currently running some tests and I noticed that there is no security warning when I open the file - no message to enable macros. 
Macro security settings are set to "Disable all macros with notification".
Why there is no notification at the opening a workbook? Are add-ins exculded from macro securities?

Comment: I think if you've installed an add-in it's inherently trusted.